# Add markers on line plot from another vector

Tags: python, numpy, vector, matplotlib, plot

I have made a line plot from `vector1` with matplotlib

```
plt.plot(vector1)
```

I have two other vectors `vector2_x` and `vector2_y` of same length.

Can I plot dots in same plot with x values from `vector2_x` and dot sizes from `vector2_y`?

Comment: Where will the y-values be coming from? `vector2_x` or `vector2_y`?

Comment: From `vector1`. The `vector2_y` will only determine the size of the markers.

Comment: You want `ax.scatter` http://matplotlib.org/examples/shapes_and_collections/scatter_demo.html

Answer (score 0):

iHave a look at  [scatterplots](http://matplotlib.org/examples/shapes_and_collections/scatter_demo.html) in matplotlib. That is a very versatile function, and you can define the marker size separately as a vector. From the example:

```
plt.scatter(x, y, s = area, c=colors, alpha=0.5)
```

Generally, best thing to do when wanting a special plot function is to peruse the [gallery](http://matplotlib.org/gallery.html#lines_bars_and_markers) and select the plot which most resembles what you want. Chances are you will find what you want there.